# Shell script inside smbclient?

Tags: bash, shell, smb

I have problem with executing shell (bash) script inside smbclient.

It looks like this:

```
rafal@amilo:~/Desktop$ 
rafal@amilo:~/Desktop$ #script.sh is here
rafal@amilo:~/Desktop$ 
rafal@amilo: smbclient //host/user -U user%password
smb: \>
smb: \> #do some automatic things here: execute script.sh from rafal@amilo
smb: \>
smb: \>exit
rafal@amilo:~/Desktop$ #now i have new files in Desktop
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: `-c` option lets you specify commands that should be "executed" inside the smb shell.

Comment: you are right, it works: 
smbclient //host/user -U user%password -c command1;command2;command3;...

Answer (score 0):

smbclient allow you to walk into samba directory. If the target server is Windows, you won't (easily) be able to run "bash script", but you can't run "batch script" using dedicated tools.
For exemple, you can use WinExec (http://sourceforge.net/projects/winexe/) or SMBMap (https://github.com/ShawnDEvans/smbmap)

Those tools have the same behaviour than PsExec from Sysinternals